# Natural width when centering a minted environment

Tags: minipage, minted, width

I'm writing a report in which I have some code snippets. Using the following code, I'm able to create, and centre, a good-looking `minted` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Required for minted
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{kvoptions}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifplatform}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{minted}

\setminted[c++]{ %
    linenos=true,             % Line numbers
    autogobble=true,          % Automatically remove common whitespace
    %bgcolor=dark-bg,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=2mm,
    fontsize=\footnotesize
}

\newenvironment{code}{%
    \VerbatimEnvironment
    \begin{figure}[thp]%
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}%
        \begin{minted}{c++}}
{%
        \end{minted}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
struct config {
    /* Default values. */
    std::string
    address = "",
    port    = "6667",
    nick    = "Temeraire",
    user    = nick,

    /* Optional */

    /* NickServ identification */
    nick_pw   = "",
    server_pw = "";

    bool ssl  = true;
};
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image: Small code snippet]

But when the same environment is used with longer code, this is the result:

[image: Long code snippet]

As seen here, `minted`'s frame lines are far from long enough, and the whole of the code is no longer centred.

While `0.4\textwidth` can be altered to fit the specific code used, it would require me to create a new environment for every code snippet I wish to include. How can the width of the environment be the same as the longest line of code?

Comment: Fixed the example.

Comment: It's quite easy to get `minted` into using `BVerbatim` instead of `Verbatim`, but, unfortunately, it seems that `BVerbatim` can't show line numbers.

Comment: doesn't quite do the right thing with varwidth, shame..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `BVerbatim` instead of `Verbatim`, but the line numbers and the frame must be added manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setminted[c++]{ %
    linenos=true,             % Line numbers
    autogobble=true,          % Automatically remove common white space
    frame=lines,
    framesep=2mm,
    fontsize=\footnotesize
}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{code}
 {\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}%
  \def\FV@BProcessLine##1{%
    \hbox{%
      \hbox to\z@{\hss\theFancyVerbLine\kern\FV@NumberSep}%
      \FancyVerbFormatLine{##1}%
    }%
  }%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \setbox\z@=\hbox\bgroup
  \begin{minted}{c++}}
 {\end{minted}\egroup
  \leavevmode\vbox{\hrule\kern2mm\box\z@\kern2mm\hrule}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{c++}
struct config {
    /* Default values. */
    std::string
    address = "",
    port    = "6667",
    nick    = "Temeraire",
    user    = nick,

    /* Optional */

    /* NickServ identification */
    nick_pw   = "",
    server_pw = "";

    bool ssl  = true;
};
\end{minted}


\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{code}
struct config {
    /* Default values. */
    std::string
    address = "",
    port    = "6667",
    nick    = "Temeraire",
    user    = nick,

    /* Optional */

    /* NickServ identification */
    nick_pw   = "",
    server_pw = "";

    bool ssl  = true;
};
\end{code}

\caption{Some centered code}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]